# Reaction between 1-methylcyclopentanol and potassium permanganate

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, organic-oxidation

In my basic organic chemistry class, I learned that only primary and secondary alcohols undergo oxidation (using $\ce{KMnO4}$).

However, what is the outcome of reacting tertiary alcohol (1-methylcyclopentanol) with a strong oxidant like $\ce{KMnO4}$ with no heat?

P.S. I am specifically interested to know what happens with no heat, because according to my minimal knowledge I know if heat was added then it is dehydration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reaction. 
*t*-BuOH may be used as a solvent for permanganate reactions. For example, see Abiko et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10/c3t9xj)].

#### References

1. Abiko, A.; Roberts, J. C.; Takemasa, T.; Masamune, S. $\ce{KMnO4}$ Revisited: Oxidation of Aldehydes to Carboxylic Acids in the Tert-Butyl Alcohol - Aqueous $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ System. *Tetrahedron Letters* **1986**, 27 (38), 4537–4540. https://doi.org/10/c3t9xj.

Comment: When do organic compounds get oxidized to CO2 then?

Comment: When you use forcing conditions: high temp. conc reagents. The OP asked about reactions without heating.